# SELECT and COUNT in one query from two tables with mySQL

Tags: mysql

Here my tables structure:

___Rooms

```
|--------|-------------|------------|
| ROO_Id | ROO_HotelId | ROO_Status |
|--------|-------------|------------|
|      1 |           1 |     active |
|      2 |           1 |     active |
|      3 |           1 |   inactive |
|--------|-------------|------------|
```

___Subscriptions

```
|-------------|-----------|
| SUB_HotelId | SUB_Limit |
|-------------|-----------|
|           1 |        24 |
|-------------|-----------|
```

---

I want to select `SUB_Limit` and count the number of rooms (only the active one).

So the query should returns me something like this:

```
|-----------|------------|
| SUB_Limit | ROO_Number |
|-----------|------------|
|        24 |          2 |
|-----------|------------|
```

Why this query do not return me the desired output please ?

```
SELECT 
    SUB_Limit, 
    COUNT(ROO_Id) AS ROO_Number
FROM ___Rooms
LEFT JOIN ___Subscriptions
    ON ___Rooms.ROO_HotelId = ___Subscriptions.SUB_HotelId
WHERE ROO_Status = 'active'
    AND SUB_HotelId = 1
    AND ROO_HotelId = 1
```

Actually, it gave me:

```
|-----------|------------|
| SUB_Limit | ROO_Number |
|-----------|------------|
|      NULL |          0 |
|-----------|------------|
```

Comment: [Nothing is wrong with your code](http://tpcg.io/bWNPSc), your problem is coming from elsewhere. This is most likely an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Answer (score 1):

Try this below query once

```
SELECT 
   SUB_Limit, COUNT(ROO_Id) AS ROO_Number FROM 
   ___rooms r,___subscriptions s 
    WHERE r.ROO_HotelId=s.SUB_HotelId AND ROO_Status='active'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below query:

```
SELECT s.sub_limit, count(ROO_Id)
FROM ___Rooms r
INNER JOIN ___Subscription s ON (s.SUB_HotelId = r.ROO_HotelId)
WHERE s.SUB_HotelId = 1
and r.ROO_STATUS = 'active'
```

Comment: Same thing than my query.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot `GROUP BY`

```
SELECT 
    S.SUB_Limit, 
    COUNT(*) AS ROO_Number
FROM ___Rooms AS R
RIGHT JOIN ___Subscriptions AS S
    ON R.ROO_HotelId = S.SUB_HotelId
WHERE R.ROO_Status = 'active'
    AND S.SUB_HotelId = 1        
GROUP BY ROO_HotelId
```

UPD: `group by` is not necessary as we need only the number of all lines. Also *RIGHT* JOIN could not be available for your particular MySQL engine (unlike LEFT JOIN or INNER JOIN), so you would better use UNION constructions, to catch zero intersections with main table if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: It do not return any row now.

Comment: Note: sometimes, I do not have rooms in `___Rooms`. So perhaps a problem with the JOIN ?